# Error: could not find function "textstat_frequency"

Tags: function, package, installation, quanteda

after installing quanteda package and loading the library, I'm still keep receiving the message: "Error: could not find function "textstat_frequency", when trying to run the function textstat_frequency. 
Why is this, can anyone help me please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to include lib path to the installation of the package. install.packages("quanteda", lib="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library") or to install further packages which could support quanteda, like Rcpp. The weirdest thing is, that the package and therefore the function is installed, but R does not recognize them when I'm trying to run the code.

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same issue and I just do the following :

```
install.packages("quanteda.textstats")
```

It is working fine for me now.

You can also try the same...

Comment: I am still facing the same error despite running your code, however, running it as follows solved the problem ```library(quanteda)
library("quanteda.textstats")```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
quanteda.bundle <- c( "quanteda", "quanteda.textmodels",
                  "quanteda.textstats", "quanteda.textplots" )
install.packages( quanteda.bundle )
```

The package has been broken up due to its large size.